# Python: Vectorize list lookup

Tags: python, vectorization

I have sensor data like this:

```
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.4,"Hp":33}
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.2,"Hp":32}
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.1,"Hp":31}
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.2,"Hp":33}
```

I'm doing a lot of list lookups in a for loop like this:

```
output={}
for i,data in enumerate(sensor_data):
    output[i]={}
    output[i]['H']=['V_Dry','Dry','Normal','Humid','V_Humid','ERR']([sensor_data[i]['Hp'])%20]
    #.... And so on for temp etc
```

Is there some way to vectorize this if I converted it to a numpy/pandas datatype? Like, if I split the sections into temp, humidity etc, is there a python method that would apply this 'mask' kind of thing on it?

Is map my only option to speed it up?

Comment: List objects do not support vectorize operations

Comment: what if I converted it to a pandas or numpy data type?

Comment: Then you can get vectorize operations.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use pandas for this.  It's pretty much made to handle data like this.

Comment: Tried that, I'm facing a significant cost to go json>pandas per line.

Answer (score 1):

**First attempt**

I suggest you first convert your data into a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
data = [{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.4,"Hp":33},
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.2,"Hp":32},
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.1,"Hp":31},
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.2,"Hp":33}]
np_data = np.asarray([list(element.values()) for element in data])
```

Now the third column is humidity in your example. Let's now define a `map` for that:

```
def convert_number_to_hr(value):
    hr_names = ['V_Dry','Dry','Normal','Humid','V_Humid','ERR']
    return hr_names[int(value//20)]
```

This uses your predefined names in steps of 20%. Now let's apply the `map`:

```
hr_humidity = map(convert_number_to_hr, np_data[:,2])
```

This is a generator. You can iterate through it or convert it to a list via `list(hr_humidity)`.

This reports a speed of

```
%timeit hr_humidity = map(convert_number_to_hr, np_data[:,2])
515 ns ± 2.25 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

If you apply `list(..)` this time grows to

```
%timeit hr_humidity = list(map(convert_number_to_hr, np_data[:,2]))
5.62 µs ± 18.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

You can now use the same procedure for everything else in your dataset.

**Second attempt**

I tried to do this fully vectorized as you asked in your comment. I came up with:

```
def same_but_pure_numpy(arr):
    arr = arr.astype(int)//20
    hr_names = np.asarray(['V_Dry','Dry','Normal','Humid','V_Humid','ERR'])
    return hr_names[arr]
```

This reports a speed of

```
%timeit a = same_but_pure_numpy(np_data[:,2])
11.5 µs ± 151 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

so the `map` version seems to be faster.

**Third attempt**

EDIT: Okay I had my first try with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.4,"Hp":33},
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.2,"Hp":32},
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.1,"Hp":31},
{"Time":1541203508.45,"Tc":25.2,"Hp":33}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def convert_number_to_hr(value):
    hr_names = ['V_Dry','Dry','Normal','Humid','V_Humid','ERR']
    return hr_names[int(value//20)]
```

The result is as expected, but it seems to consume much time:

```
%timeit new = df["Hp"].map(convert_number_to_hr)
110 µs ± 569 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: I can't find documentation about this. Is numpy+map auto-vectorized?

Comment: I edited my post. `map` is just a function that applies a function to an iterable really fast. The (as I think) fully vectorized option seems to be slower. I am no expert by any means, though. I'm open for further questions, but it's half past three in the morning here already so i might only be answering the next day

Comment: Numpy works with custom datatypes, but ID not nearly as good at it as pandas.

Comment: Okay, I tried my best; never worked with pandas :D Hope this helps someone, anyways

Comment: Unless you're going to do multiple different operations or more complex operations on the array, the cost of the conversion to and back from numpy/panda will likely overwhelm any speed advantage in the loop. Make sure you measure the speed difference if you're going that route.

Comment: I think that's why my first solution was the fastest

Comment: I fully agree that some of these methods are faster, but are they vectorized? Are multiple sections of my data being processed simultaneously?

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is made parallel inside numpy or pandas, but at least for that small dataset the overhead seems to be way higher than just using python functions. If this really for some reason has to be parallel, maybe one has to make a different approach and divide the data into chunks that are fed to multiple threads and afterwards joined. I don't see why you should want to do this, except you have gigantic datasets